# xcode 5: What's the best way to go back and forth between top of editor and where you were before?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, editor

So I've had this question for a really long time. Say:

1. You're working on line 1000 in the primary editor of xcode,
2. Then you realize you need to use class ABC but it's not imported. You go to the top of editor and write a line such as `import "abc.h"`
3. Then you want to go back to line 1000 and continue your work.

For now I've always need to use my scroll bar to scroll back and forth between line 1 and line 1000, which can easily get me lost. I know that in Eclipse+FDT you can do auto import (ctrl+1 to auto import a class), is there similar feature for xcode? If not, what's the best solution?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can jump between line numbers by typing command + l.

Comment: This is great, didn't know that you can jump between lines with command+l. However I still need to "memorize" the line number before I go to line 1. But this is good enough, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Looks like Xcode does have a "Jump to Line" feature I was unaware of, as per Jonah's answer. You can definitely use that to do what you're looking for.

---

Xcode has no auto-import feature, nor does it have a feature to jump to a specific line, unfortunately. That may get added in a future release, but I wouldn't bank on it.

Your best bet is getting creative with Xcode's snippet features and its "Jump to Next Placeholder" command — you can create "marks" in your code with snippets and placeholders, jump to the top of the files to add imports, and jump back to your "marks" to keep coding. Create a new snippet that just contains a completion placeholder:

1. Type `<#Mark#>` into any text editing application (or even a file in Xcode) and drag the text into the Snippets pane in the right sidebar. This will create a new snippet with just a placeholder called "Mark".
2. Double-click the snippet to edit its information, changing its Completion Scope to "All".
3. Give it a completion binding (like "mark") that you'll remember to use.

Then you can create a marker whenever you want (typing "mark", then hitting tab), jump to the top of the file to add an import, and use "Jump to Next Placeholder" (`^/` by default) to go back to the placeholder. You can then delete it and keep coding.

---

Alternatively, if you know `vim` keybindings and that seems too complicated, you may have some luck with the [XVim](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim) plugin for Xcode that brings some `vim` features to its editor. Keep in mind that Xcode plugins are not officially supported, so unofficial support can be taken away at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the top of the editor by pressing command-upArrow.

Then to "go back" to line 1000 (where you were), you can press control-command-leftArrow.

Comment: Odd, it worked when I tried it but definitely doesn't anymore so I must have done something weird.

But I did notice that for some reason if you navigate using cmd-L, it does save navigation points within the file.. so if you are at line 1000, then use cmd-L to go to line 1 (the top), you can actually use control-cmd-leftArrow to go back to line 1000.  (Hopefully i'm not lying again.. and at least this way you don't have to remember your line number :))